# How to make wrapped text's background span exactly across the pixel distance of that text?

Tags: html, css

This is a problem I thought is simple enough for the modern CSS to solve and I'm really confused now. I wanted to make text parent's background to span exactly across the distance between left and right of it's longest text line, and spread evenly on the sides (not like the span element does)

It's obvious that the block elements automatically goes 100% width, and inline-block would be ok, if not the behavior of text's auto wrapping mechanism, which is making bounding box 100% size as it wraps first time to the line below.

I made a simulation of a desired effect, but this workarounds are somewhat ugly. I'm interested into more simple, native solution.

Fiddle + simulation: https://jsfiddle.net/sxmkonLp/20/

Normal block element text

```
<div class="container normal">
  <h1 class="fill">Gonna wrap my text around</h1>
</div>
```

Parent element display: "inline-block" (a little closer)

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="fill inl-blk">Gonna wrap my text around</h1>
</div>
```

Text inside "span" element (closer to what I need, but not evenly spread on the sides, depends on each separate line's length)

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>
    <span>Gonna wrap my text around</span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Desired result (simulating text breaks with br and classes)

```
<div class="container text-span">
  <h1 class="fill2 inl-blk">Gonna<br class="sm4"> wrap<br class="sm3"> my<br class="sm2 sm4"> text<br class="sm1 sm3 sm4"> around</h1>
</div>
```

There goes CSS for the markup

```
html, body {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  padding: 10px;
  width: auto;
  background: orange;
  margin: 10px;
}

.container span {
  background: lightgreen;
  padding: 5px;
}

.inl-blk {
  display: inline-block;
}

.fill {
  background: yellow;
}
.fill2 {
  background: blueviolet;
  color: white;
}

.sm1,.sm2,.sm3,.sm4 {display: none;}

@media screen and (max-width: 470px) {
  .sm2 {display: none;}
  .sm3 {display: none;}
  .sm4 {display: none;}
  .sm1 {display: block;}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 350px) {
  .sm1 {display: none;}
  .sm3 {display: none;}
  .sm4 {display: none;}
  .sm2 {display: block;}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 295px) {
  .sm1 {display: none;}
  .sm2 {display: none;}
  .sm4 {display: none;}
  .sm3 {display: block;}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 242px) {
  .sm1 {display: none;}
  .sm2 {display: none;}
  .sm3 {display: none;}
  .sm4 {display: block;}
}
```

As you can see in the last example (purple box) background occupies exactly the space of the text boundary. The problem is to make that happen while the text automatically wraps into the line below

I've made some discoveries recently, like this "exotic" CSS properties "box-decoration-break: clone;" which is making span's content more like separate, block lines, but still spans across separate line length, making it unusable for my current needs. It would be cool if we have some CSS property for exactly that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've developed quite simple JS solution for this problem. In the end almost every site ends up having loads of javascript, so I find it bearable. All we need is "ResizeSensor" from this amazing package "css-element-queries"

So, we get a simple container, which keeps inside our title with h1 and div with a class "title-bg", it will be our "virtual responsive background" for the title. It gets exact text width from h1 that has display set to inline.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Should I learn Scratch before programming?</h1>
    <div class="title-bg"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here goes CSS, notice that ".title-bg" is absolute positioned, so it needed transform-50% solution to stay centered. Also z-index: 1 for h1 is needed to be visible.

```
.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  min-height: 320px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.title {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.title h1 {
  display: inline;
  /* background: orange; */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.title-bg {
  background: teal;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

And for JS all we need is set ResizeSensor to listen for event. For some reason I couldn't get it to work directly with h1 element (when set to display: inline) so I attached it to title div. The rest was to get values from h1.offsetWidth, which are exactly that of a text length. Voilà, ready and working!

```
let title = document.querySelector('.title')
let h1 = document.querySelector('.title h1')
let titleBg = document.querySelector('.title-bg')

// fire once on start
titleBg.style.width = `${h1.offsetWidth}px`
titleBg.style.height = `${h1.offsetHeight}px`

// init so it auto fires on element resize
new ResizeSensor(title, ()=> {
    titleBg.style.width = `${h1.offsetWidth}px`
  titleBg.style.height = `${h1.offsetHeight}px`
})
```

Try by yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/ktdfqhzo/52/